# Proof regarding Weistrass theorem.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof

[image]

I'm looking for feedback on my work, since we've only just started talking about continuity and differentiability and I'm not 100% confident in my knowledge.. I'd love to know if there are any inaccuracies or general tips for improvement. :)

We know $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$,

then by Weierstrass's  Theorem there exist $a ∈ [0,1]$ such that $f(a)
 ≤ f(x)$, for every $x ∈ [0,1]$.

Consider the fucntion $g: [0,f(a)]➜[0,f(a)]$, $\ g(x) = x$.

Note that by the algebra of continuous functions $g$ is continuous on
$[0,1]$.

Since $f(x)>0$ for every $x ∈ [0,1]$, and since $g(0) = 0$,$ \
 g(f(a))=f(a)$, then we have

$g(0) < \frac{f\left(a\right)}{2} < g(f(a))$.

Denote $\frac{f\left(a\right)}{2} = ϵ$.

Then we proved the existance of an ϵ > 0 such that f(x) > ϵ for every x
∈ [0,1].

I was originally planning to use the intermediate value theorem after finding the element between the two values of g, but then I noticed that I don't actually need to and I've already found such an element..
Is there anything I can improve?

Comment: Too long: the minimum of $\f;f\;$ is $\;a\;$ and exists by Weierstrass Theorem II, so for all $\;x\in[0,1]\;,\;\;f(x)\ge f(a)>\epsilon:=\frac{f(a)}2\;$ and we're done...

Comment: You can also give a proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no reason for introducing that function $g$. You defined $\varepsilon$ as $\frac{f(a)}2$. Then you can simply say that, for each $x\in[0,1]$,\begin{align}f(x)&\geqslant f(a)\\&>\frac{f(a)}2\text{ (since $f(a)>0$)}\\&=\varepsilon.\end{align}

Comment: Nice! You're right.

Comment: @MathCurious  If nice then upvote it. +1